# Replace empty cells in R with consecutive values (R, loops)

Tags: r, string, loops, dplyr

I have a dataset, df, one of the columns contains blank values, I need these to be filled. How do I fill the blank "" fields with consecutive values?  (I have a dataset that contains over 10,000 rows)

```
                   Subject Folder

                   hi      outlookdata
                   hi      outlookdata
                   hi      outlookdata
                           outlookdata
                           outlookdata
                   hello   outlookdata
                   hello   outlookdata
                           outlookdata
                           outlookdata 
                           outlookdata
                           outlookdata
                   hi      outlookdata
```

This is my desired output:

```
                   Subject Folder

                   hi      outlookdata
                   hi      outlookdata
                   hi      outlookdata
                   a       outlookdata
                   a       outlookdata
                   hello   outlookdata
                   hello   outlookdata
                   b       outlookdata
                   b       outlookdata 
                   b       outlookdata
                   b       outlookdata
                   goodbye outlookdata
```

Here is the dput for my data:

```
 structure(list(Subject = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "goodbye", "hello", "hi"
 ), class = "factor"), Folder = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "outlookdata", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",     row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I was not sure if I should use a loop?

```
   for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
          if(df$Subject[i]=="")({ 
          df$Subject[i]=df$Subject[i-1] 
        }
     }
```

I am wanting the values that replace the "" to be consecutive.
Any suggestion is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` for this.  The 'Subject' column was `factor`, so it is converted to `character` otherwise assigning new values would require either changing the `levels` by adding or calling `factor` again.   Convert to `data.table` (`setDT`), create a vector of values for replacement ('nm1'), In the dataest, create the new column 'grp' by `rleid` on the 'Subject', then groupedd by 'grp',if the 'Subject' is blank (specify it on the `i`), then assign (`j`) the 'Subject' as the value from 'nm1' corresponding to the numeric index provided by `.GRP`, and then remove the 'grp' by assigning to `NULL`

```
library(data.table)
df1$Subject <- as.character(df1$Subject)
nm1 <- c(letters, do.call(paste0, expand.grid(letters, 1:1000)))
setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(Subject)][Subject == "", 
      Subject := nm1[.GRP], grp][, grp := NULL][]
#    Subject      Folder
# 1:      hi outlookdata
# 2:      hi outlookdata
# 3:      hi outlookdata
# 4:       a outlookdata
# 5:       a outlookdata
# 6:   hello outlookdata
# 7:   hello outlookdata
# 8:       b outlookdata
# 9:       b outlookdata
#10:       b outlookdata
#11:       b outlookdata
#12: goodbye outlookdata
```

Comment: With 10000 rows `letters` is probably not enough, or am I missing something?

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic. sorry, I didn't catch that part

Comment: @RuiBarradas, yes you are right! If it is numbers, maybe the pattern can double up, AA, or A1 etc I am not sure

Comment: hi @akrun, what would the consecutive values be? would it be numbers?

Comment: @TanishaHudson. I made the correction.  Now, it would be 'nm1' of length 26026 would cover that

Comment: Let me try this now. Thank you. @Akrun is there a possibility that the values could be alphanumeric?

Comment: Thank you! I wish to be experts just like you all one day. Very inspirational. Thank you

Comment: @TanishaHudson  You can create any sort of values with `paste` i.e. `nm1 <- c(letters, do.call(paste0, expand.grid(letters, letters,  1:100)))`

Comment: @TanishaHudson Thank you for your kind words.  You will definitely become an expert with the kind of dedication you have.

Comment: Thank you @Akrun!! you guys are amazing!!